# Send results to the same web part

Tags: web-part, search-results

I have to web parts with documents in a page.
When I use the search box the results are showed in the other web part.
I would like the results to be in the same web part.

I see that when modifying for example web part 1 there is Connections/Send row to Web Part 2. But I cannot send the results to web part1, even disabling the connections.

So, how to send Web Part 1 results to Web part 1 ?

Comment: There are so many variables to your question. Do you mean you have to document library view webparts on your page? If not can you give me the exact type of each webpart? What version of SharePoint are we talking about?

Comment: Why does it need to be the same web part?

Comment: Yes @Chromanin I have two document library view parts one beside the other. I am using SharePoint 2013 on premises.

Comment: @z.rahui I need the result in the same web part because the search is referred to that web part. As the results end up in the other web part, they are a bit misleading

Comment: Thats how the Search Web parts work. If you look at the Search Results page on the Search Centre you will see that the query is directed to the Results web part. From a users point of view, it's not misleading at all. They see a Search Box and results. There are properties that change this behaviour slightly (Inplace Query, Results page, etc)